# Error in recvfrom in C socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Sorry for my not perfet english

I have to implement reliable communication using UDP protocol; for start, i'm tring realize a simple program; a client send a message to server with NULL in buffer; the servers understands it as a request, then sends to client response, which is a number;

code client:

```
/*
 * newClient.c
 *
 *  Created on: 22 lug 2017
 *      Author: claudio
 */


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERV_PORT   5193
#define MAXLINE     1024


void err_exit(char* str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}




int request_to_server(int sockfd,int* x,struct sockaddr_in addr)
{
    int n;
    if(sendto(sockfd, NULL, 0, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr,    sizeof(addr)) < 0)
        err_exit("sendto\n");
    n = recvfrom(sockfd,(char*)x,sizeof(int),0,NULL,NULL);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("errore in recvfrom");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(n > 0) {
       printf("client received: %d\n",*(int*)x);
    }
    return 1;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
  int   sockfd;
  struct    sockaddr_in   servaddr;
  int x;

  if (argc != 2) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "utilizzo: daytime_clientUDP <indirizzo IP  server>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) { /* crea il socket   */
      perror("errore in socket");
      exit(1);
    }

    memset((void *)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        err_exit("error in inet_pton for %s");
    }



  if(request_to_server(sockfd,&x,servaddr))
      printf("client received %d from server\n",x);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

this is server code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERV_PORT   5193
#define MAXLINE     1024



void err_exit(char* str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


int generate_casual()
{
    int x = random()%1000 + 1;      //number between 1 and 1000
    return x;
}



void listen_request(int sockfd,char* buff,struct sockaddr_in* addr,socklen_t* len)
{
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr = *addr;
    socklen_t l = *len;
    printf("listening request\n");
     if ( (recvfrom(sockfd, buff, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &l)) < 0){
         printf("errno code: %d\n",errno);
         err_exit("recvfrom\n");
    }
     *addr = servaddr;
     *len = l;
     return;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;
  int sockfd;
  socklen_t len;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  char buff[MAXLINE];
  srand(time(NULL));


  memset((void *)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
  addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT); /* numero di porta del server */


  if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
      err_exit("errore in socket");

   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
     perror("errore in bind");
     exit(1);
   }

  listen_request(sockfd,buff,&addr,&len);

  int n_ack = generate_casual();
  //char* p =(char*)&n_ack;
  if (sendto(sockfd, (char*)&n_ack, sizeof(int), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
      err_exit("sendto");
  }
  printf("server: client is connected\n");
  return 0;
}
```

when i run, sometimes client receives correctly number; but sometimes i have an error on recvfrom with msg "Invalid argument" ed errno code is 22;
why this?I have no idea in which case it runs and when it doesn't work, code is the same..

Comment: Why are you calling `sendto()` with a null buffer?

Comment: 'listen_request(sockfd,buff,&addr,&len);' address of an uninitialised var, (len), passed in.  While this is not necessarily always an error, it is in this case.  The function  recvfrom() is expected the pointer target to be loaded with the length of the 'sockaddr' struct;(

Comment: Cool lets use udp for the thing it was engineered and optimized to not be. Hope is for academic purposes other wise just use TCP.

Comment: thank you Martin, it was a very stupid error..Why sometimes program runs also with this error?It was a mechanism of operating system ?

Comment: You aren't sending with NULL in the buffer, whatever that means. Yui are trying to send with a null pointer *instead of* a buffer. This is not specified to work.

Comment: @JeanBaptisteYun If you're going to edit a typo don't just perpetrate another one.

Comment: @ClaudioSantoro Sometimes it might work 'cos the value is big enough, it might fail others, maybe nasal demons tomorrow?